# Asp.Net Core very slow request-per-second on out of the box projects

Tags: performance, asp.net-core, .net-5

Starting a default Asp.Net Core 5 WebAPI project and throwing apache ab at it shows that by default it's handing ~380 requests/s with blank `Ok()` responses. I tried this on multiple devices, Ryzen 7 2700x, i7-6700k, and a Xeon e5-2650v4. They all gave similar results.

- Asp.Net 5
- Running Windows 10 (and Server 2016) - Kestrel
- Default starting project with a controller method returning Ok()
- Similar results when returning data with response caching (~380 RPS).

[image]

Posts like this indicate ~40k requests/s: https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2018/Dec/31/Dont-let-ASPNET-Core-Default-Console-Logging-Slow-your-App-down

- Why is this so slow right out of the box?
- Is this expected behavior?
- Is it possible to get more reasonable request/second out of asp.net core?

Edit:

**More information**

- This is over HTTPS. with just HTTP I'm getting ~4000 requests/s and pulling 70% CPU utilization
- With HTTPS I'm getting ~300 RPS and pulling ~2-3% CPU utilization

Comment: What's the command you're running for the tests? Are tests running against an already running instance?

Comment: The tests are running against a running production instance (not through Visual Studio). `ab -n 1500 -c 15 https://192.168.2.11:5000/test` where `test` is just returning `Ok()`

Comment: Note that during these tests, CPU usage might go up by 2-3%. Despite not getting any further performance out of the webserver.